# É possivel restringir acesso a informações de variáveis com AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, express.js

Olá,

Sou novo em desenvolvimento e gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de ocultar informações de variáveis no AngularJs  , estou usando uma API do MongoLab e não queria deixar minha apiKey visível para qualquer pessoa que debugar o código no navegador, estou rodando a aplicação com NodeJs e ExpressJs , o codigo do server foi gerado através do `ExpressJS CLI` dessa maneira: `npm install express-generator -g` e logo em seguida `express meuApp`.

Segue código do controller:

```
app.controller("RBScontroller", function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.enviar = function enviar(){

    var ApiMongo = 'https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/db_test/collections/users?apiKey=Chave_da_APi';  //Gostaria de esconder essa informação
    $scope.users = [];
    $scope.loading = true;

    $http.get(ApiMongo).success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.users = data;
        $scope.loading = false; 

    }).error(function(msg) {      

        angular.element($(function(){alert("Fail")}));
        $scope.loading = false;
    });
 }  
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A resposta simples é **não**, não há maneira de ocultar do lado do cliente. E, ainda que existisse, a URL chamada poderia ser interceptada (via debug tools).

Entretanto, você pode utilizar uma abordagem diferente. Ao invés de realizar a chamada via Angular, utilize uma função via `http.request` no NodeJS, e retorne o resultado para a sua aplicação.

Comment: Ah, você já tinha respondido isso aí. A leitura dinâmica me impossibilitou de ver o trecho do `http.request`. +1

Comment: Valeu cara , vou pesquisar então como faz isso no NodeJS! ;)

Answer (score 3):

Amigo, não existe maneira de fazer isso através do javascript.

A única coisa que pode ser feita - e é o que eu faria se tivesse que esconder essa informação - é fazer um `proxying`.

Traduzindo, você vai mandar a informação para o seu servidor, e seu servidor por sua vez fará a requisição que você precisa - ao invés de fazer diretamente.

Exemplificando com PHP

```
#requisicao.php

$conteudo = file_get_contents('https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/db_test/collections/users?apiKey=Chave_da_APi');

return Response::json($conteudo);
```

Javascript:

```
$scope.enviar = function enviar(){

    var ApiMongo = 'requisicao.php'; // A informação só é vista pelo programador que acessar requisicao.php
    $scope.users = [];
    $scope.loading = true;

    $http.get(ApiMongo).success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.users = data;
        $scope.loading = false; 

    }).error(function(msg) {      

        angular.element($(function(){alert("Fail")}));
        $scope.loading = false;
    });
 }  
});
```

No caso, como você está usando `node.js` do lado do servidor, creio que você poderia fazer isso.

Comment: +1, descrição mais elaborada. =)

Comment: Valeu Wallace, com node não sei como faz , acho que vou ter que usar alguma outra linguagem então, esse exemplo que você mostrou me parece simples de fazer , vou tentar! ;)

Comment: Que isso, rapaz? como não sabe? O @OnoSendai deu a dica: use `http.request` para capturar as informações